# How to use Directory.GetFiles in VB?

Tags: vb.net

I basically follow a MS example.The following is the example.

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO

Public Class Test
Public Shared Sub Main()
    Try 
        ' Only get files that begin with the letter "c." 
        Dim dirs As String() = Directory.GetFiles("c:\", "c*")
        Console.WriteLine("The number of files starting with c is {0}.", dirs.Length)
        Dim dir As String 
        For Each dir In dirs
            Console.WriteLine(dir)
        Next 
    Catch e As Exception
        Console.WriteLine("The process failed: {0}", e.ToString())
    End Try 
End Sub 
End Class
```

I modify a little bit, so that I can use it as file search function. However there is an error at "For Each f In Directory.GetFiles(d, FileName)". What do I do wrong?

```
    Public Sub DirSearch(ByVal sDir As String, ByVal FileName As String)
    Dim d As String
    Dim f As String

    Try
        For Each d In Directory.GetDirectories(sDir)
            For Each f In Directory.GetFiles(d, FileName)
                If f = FileName Then
                    Form1.TextBox4.Text = "1"
                Else
                    Form1.TextBox4.Text = "0"
                End If
            Next
            DirSearch(d, FileName)
        Next
    Catch excpt As System.Exception
        Debug.WriteLine(excpt.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: what exactly is the error you're getting?

Comment: this code ran ok on my machine; however, I don't think your logic is correct. The intent of the check f = FileName is not clear. "f" will be the complete path and "FileName" is a filename or a search expression NOT containing the path; I don't think the IF condition will ever be satisfied.

Comment: @JimO'Neil You are right. I have logical error in my program

Comment: @JimO'Neil Do you have any suggestion of how I should change my code?

Comment: depends on what it's supposed to do :) are you just trying to find if a given file exists in some subdirectory?  Is "FileName" always a real file name, or might it be using a search pattern like ? and *.

Comment: @JimO'Neil I want to do a file search in a Folder which contains many level subfolders (e.g. Folder>Folder1>...>FolderX). I want to find whether a file "abc.txt" in any of those subfolders, if exist then copy to a default folder.

Answer (score 1):

I find this, this solve my problem

```
Public Sub DirSearch(ByVal sDir As String, ByVal FileName As String)
    For Each foundFile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(sDir, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, FileName)
       "Do the work here"
    Next
End Sub
```