# finding file names which consist its name as variable

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

i am using visual studio 2010

i need a expression to find a file name for eg *.xml is used for finding file name "test.xml" so what will be the expression to find a file name 4374573.xml

i have tried

File.ReadAllLines(TextBox1.Text & "*.xml") but it is only applicable for characters anything for variables.

any help will be appreciable

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking how to find files on disk, you can use the GetFiles method as in [how-to-use-directory-getfiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12252164/how-to-use-directory-getfiles-in-vb). For more details check:[MSDN-GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for

```
Dim path as String = "C:\YourFolder" 
Dim fileCollection = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(path, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, "*.XML")
```

It will search for every .XML file at the specified path and returns the file list in `fileCollection`